# I want to print out quickly because the for statement is too large

Tags: python

The code I wrote is as follows.
But the formoon is too long, so it takes a long time
Is there any way I can print out the value I want quickly?

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from itertools import combinations    

arr = np.arange(512)
r = np.power(2,9)
rand_num = random.randrange(0,r)

for i, combi in enumerate(combinations(arr, r)):
    if i == rand_num: print(combi); break
```

Comment: `print(combinations(arr, r)[rand_num])`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I skipped the code.   --> from itertools import combinations

Comment: print ( list(combinations(arr,r)[rand_num] )                   This ensures that the size is too large to run.